# socket stall during big transfer

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I'm currently working on a file tranfert program using .net socket but i came to a problem :
My receiving socket seam to "stall" when i attempt to transfert a lot of data (~ 2Mo). I'm sending my file by little segment (~ 10ko) for various reason

Here is my reveiver code (on my client socket) :

```
public ClientSocket(string _IP, int _port)
    {
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        this.IP = _IP;
        this.port = _port;
        StateObject so = new StateObject(clientSocket);
        this.clientConnection = new ClientConnection(so);
        Logs.Print(Logs.LogType.INFO, "Tentative de connexion à " + this.IP + ":" + this.port);
        try
        {
            so.socket.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(this.IP), this.port);
            Logs.Print(Logs.LogType.INFO, "Connecté à " + this.IP + ":" + this.port);
            so.socket.BeginReceive(so.buffer, 0, StateObject.bufferSize, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(this.ReceiveCallback), so);                
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            Logs.Print(Logs.LogType.ERROR, "Erreur lors de la connexion : Code " + ex.ErrorCode + " | Message : " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        StateObject so = (StateObject)asyncResult.AsyncState;
        int read = so.socket.EndReceive(asyncResult);
        Logs.Print(Logs.LogType.DEBUG, "Réception de " + read + " Octets");
        // Transfert du buffer primaire au buffer de stockage secondaire
        for (int i = 0; i < read; i++)
            so.subBuffer.Enqueue(so.buffer[i]);

        uint dataUsed = this.clientConnection.Receive(so.subBuffer);
        for (uint i = 0; i < dataUsed; i++)
            so.subBuffer.Dequeue();
        so.socket.BeginReceive(so.buffer, 0, StateObject.bufferSize, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(this.ReceiveCallback), so);
    }
```

I use a storage object "StateObject" to keep a reference to the socket whithin and an access to the receiving buffer array and a subbuffer in wich the buffer is emptied into each time the receivecallback is called.

And here my sender code (on my server socket) :

```
public void Send(int id, DataContainer dataContainer)
{
        Packet[] packets = this.ClientsSockets[id].Send(dataContainer);
        for (int i = 0; i < packets.Length; i++)
        {
            Logs.Print(Logs.LogType.DEBUG, "Envoi de " + packets[i].ToBinary().Length + " octets");

            this.ClientsSockets[id].stateObject.socket.Send(packets[i].ToBinary());
        }
    }
```

Have any of you experienced this kind of problem ?

Comment: Do you require every single bytes to be `Enqueue()`/`Dequeue()`'d separately? If not, `Buffer.BlockCopy()` is a faster way to copy a block of bytes. And since you don't `BeginReceive()` again before having processed the data, you could probably even process the primary buffer instead.

Comment: try doing your transfer through localhost.  Does the problem still occur?  If not, I would suspect a network issue.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis I will try to switch to an array instread of a queue, i'll get back to you. atRussell Uhl Yes it happend as well in local as in remote